# MSSql get week of a date

Tags: sql-server

I using a old version of mssql express and my reports that includes went bananas.

```
SELECT 
   DATEPART(wk, '2021-01-01'),
   DATEPART(wk, '2021-01-02'),
   DATEPART(wk, '2021-01-03'),
   DATEPART(wk, '2021-01-04'),
   DATEPART(wk, '2021-01-05'), 
   DATEPART(wk, '2021-01-06'), 
   DATEPART(wk, '2021-01-07')
```

Return

```
1,1,1,1,2,2,2
```

I ended up doing:

```
select DATEPART(y,[date])/7+(DATEPART(y,[date])%7)/4
```

And that made the trick for now, but is flawed.
But is there some sane way in mssql to define what type of week you want using just the query? (can't run a set before).
I want weeks to start on mondays first week have no. 1 and first week of year is when there is more than 3days in that week.
In mysql that would be:

```
select week([date],3)
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `DATEPART(wk,`. The results are expected.  What does `went bananas.` mean? What did you expect?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well technically they didn't went bananas, I'm sure that the week it's gives is correct somewhere in the world. But where I live, and the people receiving the report lives 2020-12-28 to 2021-01-03 was week 53, 2021-01-04 to 2020-01-10 was week 1.
So for the users it's bananas as reports from all other system say it was week 1 last week except from this report that say it was week 2.

Comment: Did you mix up the years perhaps, and used `2020` instead of `2021`? All those numbers are correct for weeks that start on Sunday.

Comment: Dates are the same all over the world. Week numbers though have two different definitions (calendar and ISO week number), because years don't start on a Sunday or Monday. There are different rules that specify which number is used for the last week in a year. The start of the week on the other hand differs per *company* or even department in the same company. So what did you actually expect?

Comment: `where I live, and the people receiving the report lives` I bet their HR  department would disagree. If you want to use the ISO Week number, use `isowk`. `SELECT 
   DATEPART(wk, '2021-01-01'), DATEPART(isowk, '2021-01-01')` returns `1,53`

Comment: Look at what your expected values are. `2021-01-03` should be week 53? The first three days of 2021 are week 53? That's not what anyone would expect, no matter where they live, *unless they are accountants*. And even then, they wouldn't call it week 53 outside their office. What you asked for is the ISO Week number

Comment: ISO Week numbers [are explained in the DATEPART documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#iso_week-datepart). Financial reporting if more complex than that though, with different companies having different reporting calendars. Some start their fiscal year in July for example

Comment: THANKS. Indeed it was isoweek I needed.